# How to found out, which instances are using which service accounts in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, service-accounts, google-iam

I want to delete service accounts, but I'm not sure whether any instances are using those service accounts or not. How to find out, whether a service account is being used?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the Google Cloud Console, the CLI `gcloud` and the SDK in your favorite language. What problem are you having and with which one?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the most straightforward way to see the list of service accounts attached to GCE instances is to use the `gcloud` CLI.

Replace PROJECT_ID as needed:

```
gcloud compute instances list --format="get(serviceAccounts.email)" --project PROJECT_ID | uniq | sort
```

You can conveniently run this command in your Cloud Shell.